# From mongod to pouchdb/couchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I want to migrate my app from mongodb to pouchdb/couchdb for the syncing. But I am lost. My app has 20 collections in a mongo database. One collection holds the users, who can only view content they created in the other collections, using their ids. I implemented my own user management system. Now, with 'one database per user', do i have to create 19 databases for each user or put everything into one database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since CouchDB 1.6.1 does not support permission on document level, you have 4 options as I see it:

1. To use fork of Couch DB called rCouch - [here](http://rcouch.org/)
2. Wait for CouchDB 2.0 that will merge the codebase of rCouch and CouchDB and allow you to use user permission on document level
3. Use Couchbase and [Couchbase sync gateway](http://developer.couchbase.com/mobile/develop/guides/sync-gateway/) with PouchDB that will allow you to define rights per documents
4. Go with one db per user in CouchDB

Good luck with whatever you choose. Couchbase sync gateway in my personal opinion is not easy.

Comment: Neither rCouch, nor CouchDB 2 support doc-grade ACL.

Comment: Disagree. Check this https://github.com/rcouch/rcouch/wiki/Validate-documents-on-read

Comment: Well, what about map indexes? Reduce? What about attachments? Are their results are ACl-controlled by rCouch? Afaik, no.